# iOS Client connecting to server using socketrocket results in "Stream end encountered"

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, websocket, socketrocket

```
NSString *urlString = @"ip address";
self.webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
self.webSocket.delegate = self;
[self.webSocket open];
```

Here `didCloseWithCode` is called with reason `Stream end encountered`.

Any ideas about what might go wrong?

Comment: I have some problem with wss:// - do you have a solution?

Comment: I am having the same problem with wss:// connections works fine with the ws:// though.

Comment: any one found any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the issue is, socket rocket library version is different from client and server. You have to use the same version for both server and client.